# Anonymous function in Coffeescript how to test it

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jasmine

I know there's a lot of discussions in Stackoverflow about this one, but I couldn't get a straight answer about that. And I don't know much of coffeescript.

Basically, I have this coffeescript

`return42 = ->
    42`

And when I compile I get this

```
(function() {
  var return42;

  return42 = function() {
    return 42;
  };

}).call(this);
```

So the function it's wrapped in the anonymous function which it's not exposed to the world. So when I write this test

```
describe "Test number", ->
    it "is 42", ->
        expect(return42()).toBe 42
```

The test would fail because return42() is undefined. How could I solve this.

Thank you very much. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a global variable as the entry point to your program. You can accomplish that by attaching your function to the global object instead of leaving it local to the function. Try this this instead:

```
@return42 = -> 42
```

which will give you:

```
(function() {
  this.return42 = function() {
    return 42;
  };
}).call(this);
```

If you are only running this in the browser and not Node.js, it would be a bit more idiomatic to attach to `window` instead of `this`, even though they are both the global object in this case.

Answer (score 0):

While Jimmy is right, I would add that if you don't need to expose the function then you don't need to test it.  Instead test the public APIs that use that function.  So long as your public API depends on your private implementations, then the tests should fail if the private functions fail too.