# Testing of Backbone code inside anonymous function using Jasmine and Sinon

Tags: testing, backbone.js, bdd, jasmine, sinon

Here are snippet from my code

```
(function(){
var BootModel = Backbone.View.extend();
    var BootApp = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function(options) {
            //some logical code
    },
    render : function() {
        //some more logical code
    }
});
new BootApp({
    aggregatedEvent : _.extend({}, Backbone.Events),
    model: new BootModel()
});
})();
```

Now as you can see I have logical code goes inside my views, I need to test these view using Jasmine, but in my case everything is inside private scope (I did this thing to prevent accessing of my code from external dev tool like firebug and modifying my model or any attribute state )

I tried many things looked into Sinon to understand if I can use Spy but nothing worked for me

Similar question could be : [Anonymous function in Coffeescript how to test it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8242086/anonymous-function-in-coffeescript-how-to-test-it)

I want to understand where I going wrong?
Is my approach for hiding everything inside Anonymous function is wrong?
If Yes then what would be best practice for such implementation ? 
If No then How I am going to test this kind of code

PS : I am not in favor of backdoor manipulation.

Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: I think you'll have to refactor your code to make those views accessible to the outside world. You can still use your build/deployment system to mash them together inside a function if you want. Either that or you'd need testing hooks hard wired so that you could get inside that function and add the spies.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks I am trying by making everything in global namespace scope

Comment: Can we some of your test code?

Answer (score 0):

A spy replaces the function it is spying on, so use it as such:

```
describe("Backbone View Tester", foo)

function foo()
 {
 it('should work' , bar)
 }

function bar()
 {
 spyOn(foo, 'setbar');
 spyOn(foo, 'setbaz').and.callThrough();

 foo.setbar = function()
            {
            var BootModel = Backbone.View.extend();
            var BootApp = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize : function(options) 
               {
               //some logical code
               },
            render : function() 
               {
               //some more logical code
               }
            };

  foo.setbaz = new BootApp(
            {
            aggregatedEvent : _.extend({}, Backbone.Events),
            model: new BootModel()
            });
        };

 foo.setbar();
 foo.setbaz();

 expect(_.extend).toHaveBeenCalled();
 expect(Backbone.View.extend).toHaveBeenCalled();
 }
```

**References**

- [Jasmine Wiki: Spies](https://github.com/btakita/jasmine#user-content-spies)
- [Unit test JavaScript applications with Jasmine](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/unit-test-javascript-applications-with-jasmine.html)
- [Spy on Backbone.js View Functions with Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056720/)
- [JavaScript Unit Testing with Jasmine: Part 2](http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/javascript-unit-testing-with-jasmine-part-2/)